# Python string comparison not matching a line read from a file

Tags: python, text-files, line-by-line

I have got a text file with keywords in each line like so:

```
foo
foo1
^^^^^^^^^
foo5
foo7
```

`^^^^^^^^^` is a flag set to break the for loop once reached:

```
keywords = []
    with open("keywords.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith(request.GET.get('search', '')):
                keywords.append(line.lower())
            if line == "^^^^^^^^^":
                break
```

In above code, the second condition is never met (`**if line == "^^^^^^^^^":**`).

I also tried `is` instead of `==` (but did not expect it to work, and it didn't).

When I tried `line.startswith("^^^^^^"):`, the condition is met, and loop is ended. I'm wondering why `==` doesn't work in the above case.

Looking for some direction and explanation.

Comment: Did you try with newline '\n' at the end? Use `repr(line)` to see the actual contents of the line.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @AshwiniChaudhary, that will come in handy next time I face similar issue. I added \n at the end of the string and the condition passed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There probably is a line break or other whitespace at the end of the line, so `==` won't work, unless you trim it first:

```
if line.strip() == "^^^^^^^^^":
```

Comment: This did the trick, thanks :)